# How to maintain devexpress gridview data for each call back function without using static variable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, gridview, devexpress

I have written following code for datagrid.
Controller:

```
public class EmployeeController : BaseController
{
    public static List<EmployeeModel> Employees { get; set; }
    public ActionResult EmployeeSearchPartial()
    {
        return PartialView("EmployeeSearchPartial", Employees);
    }
}
```

EmployeeSearch partial view

```
@Html.DevExpress().GridView(
settings =>
{
    settings.Name = "gvEmployeeSearch";
    settings.KeyFieldName = "EmployeeId";
    settings.SettingsPopup.EditForm.Width = 600;
    settings.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "Employee", Action = "EmployeeSearchPartial" };
    settings.Width = 720;
    settings.Height = 600;
    settings.SettingsPager.PageSize = 15;
    settings.Settings.VerticalScrollBarStyle = DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.GridViewVerticalScrollBarStyle.Standard;
    settings.Settings.VerticalScrollableHeight = 350;
    settings.ControlStyle.Paddings.Padding = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Pixel(0);
    settings.ControlStyle.Border.BorderWidth = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Pixel(0);
    settings.ControlStyle.BorderBottom.BorderWidth = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Pixel(1);
    settings.SettingsText.EmptyDataRow = "";
    settings.SettingsBehavior.AllowFocusedRow = true;
    settings.ClientSideEvents.RowClick = "OnCellClick";
    settings.Columns.Add(column =>
    {
        column.Caption = "Employee Name";
        column.FieldName = "Name";
        column.Width = 420;
    });
    settings.Columns.Add(column =>
    {
        column.Caption = "Employee Number";
        column.FieldName = "EmployeeId";
        column.Width = 300;
    });      
}).Bind(Model).GetHtml()
```

Now in the above code, the grid uses callback functions for sorting, filtering any other functionality. When the grid calls a callback function, a new object gets created for EmployeeController so as to maintain employee datascrourse (Employees). We have to create a static variable in the controller to maintain the grid datascrouse list. It is ok for a single user, but when multiple users access that page then the grid value gets a conflict because MVC is a web application so multiple users can access same page at the same time.

Please share any solution to maintain the grid view data for each call back function.

Comment: does any one got solution